# How to fix getsockname failed: EBADF (Bad file number)?

Tags: java, android, network-programming

My application does `network operations`, like `socket` creation, sending and receiving the `TCP` packets. Some times i will get this below exception which i was unable to fix. I have tried with all possible fixes but as it is fatal exception my application will be crashed and closed which is very annoying.

What are possible things we can make to avoid this issue or atleast can avoid crashing ??

Any helps will be highly appreciated !!

```
01-24 10:29:27.675: E/AndroidRuntime(3781): java.lang.AssertionError: libcore.io.ErrnoException: getsockname failed: EBADF (Bad file number)
01-24 10:29:27.675: E/AndroidRuntime(3781):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.getSocketLocalAddress(IoBridge.java:583)
01-24 10:29:27.675: E/AndroidRuntime(3781):     at java.net.Socket.cacheLocalAddress(Socket.java:950)
01-24 10:29:27.675: E/AndroidRuntime(3781):     at java.net.Socket.startupSocket(Socket.java:568)
01-24 10:29:27.675: E/AndroidRuntime(3781):     at java.net.Socket.tryAllAddresses(Socket.java:127)
01-24 10:29:27.675: E/AndroidRuntime(3781):     at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:177)
01-24 10:29:27.675: E/AndroidRuntime(3781):     at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:149)
```

PS : Here is my sample code :

```
InetAddress local_inet_addr = null;
    try {
        Socket socket = new Socket("www.xxxxxxx.com", 80);
        if (socket != null) {
            local_inet_addr = socket.getLocalAddress();
            socket.close();
            socket = null;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        try {
            Socket socket = new Socket("www.yyyyyyyy.net", 80);
            if (socket != null) {
                local_inet_addr = socket.getLocalAddress();
                socket.close();
                socket = null;
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
    }
```

Here xxxx and yyyy will be my personal domain names.

Comment: please post your code.

Comment: 'socket' cannot possibly be null at the points you're testing it. Don't write pointless code. This seems to be just a way for you to discover your own IP address, in which case it's an unduly expensive one. There are methods provided in InetAddress for that.